# When toolStripProgressBar1 and toolStripLabel1 are displayed in winform, the listView1 in the previous position does not disappear

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code implementation in c# winform.
The input box is ToolStripTextBox displayed on the top line.
The progress bar ToolStripProgressBar is below the ToolStripTextBox.
The progress of the progress bar ToolStripLabel is below the ToolStripProgressBar.

DoubleBufferListView is displayed below ToolStripLabel.

However, the moment the ToolStripProgressBar and ToolStripLabel are displayed, their location still shows the first item of the DoubleBufferListView.

The code is as follows.

```
    using CommonTools;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace EWPEditor.Plugin.UI
    {
    partial class MainPane
    {
        /// \
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// \
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        ///  
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// 

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    
        #region Component Designer generated code
    
        ///  
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// 
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
            this.toolStripButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripSeparator3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.toolStripButton4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripButton13 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripSeparator2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.toolStripButton8 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripButton2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.toolStripSplitButton3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSplitButton();
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.toolStripSeparator1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.imageList1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);
            this.导出文档ToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.listView1 = new CommonTools.DoubleBufferListView();
            this.columnHeader1 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new  System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
            this.toolStripTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox();
            this.toolStripProgressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar();
            this.toolStripLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel();
            this.toolStrip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
            this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.contextMenuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.toolStrip2.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // toolStrip1
            // 
            this.toolStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.toolStrip1.GripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
            this.toolStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
            this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripButton1,
            this.toolStripSeparator3,
            this.toolStripButton4,
            this.toolStripButton13,
            this.toolStripSeparator2,
            this.toolStripButton8,
            this.toolStripButton2,
            this.toolStripSplitButton3});
            this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
            this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 33);
            this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
            // 
            // toolStripButton1
            // 
            this.toolStripButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton1.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_arrow_up;
            this.toolStripButton1.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton1.Name = "toolStripButton1";
            this.toolStripButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.toolStripButton1.Text = "上一级";
            this.toolStripButton1.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.Overlay;
            this.toolStripButton1.ToolTipText = "上一级";
            this.toolStripButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripButton1_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator3
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator3.Name = "toolStripSeparator3";
            this.toolStripSeparator3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(6, 33);
            // 
            // toolStripButton4
            // 
            this.toolStripButton4.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton4.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_add;
            this.toolStripButton4.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripButton4.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton4.Name = "toolStripButton4";
            this.toolStripButton4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.toolStripButton4.Text = "一键插入";
            this.toolStripButton4.ToolTipText = "一键插入";
            this.toolStripButton4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripButton4_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripButton13
            // 
            this.toolStripButton13.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton13.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_reload;
            this.toolStripButton13.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripButton13.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton13.Name = "toolStripButton13";
            this.toolStripButton13.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.toolStripButton13.Text = "刷新";
            this.toolStripButton13.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripButton13_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator2
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator2.Name = "toolStripSeparator2";
            this.toolStripSeparator2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(6, 33);
            // 
            // toolStripButton8
            // 
            this.toolStripButton8.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton8.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_site_map;
            this.toolStripButton8.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripButton8.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton8.Name = "toolStripButton8";
            this.toolStripButton8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.toolStripButton8.Text = "新建文件夹";
            this.toolStripButton8.ToolTipText = "新建文件夹";
            this.toolStripButton8.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripButton8_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripButton2
            // 
            this.toolStripButton2.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripButton2.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_file;
            this.toolStripButton2.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripButton2.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripButton2.Name = "toolStripButton2";
            this.toolStripButton2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.toolStripButton2.Text = "上传文件";
            this.toolStripButton2.ToolTipText = "上传文件";
            this.toolStripButton2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripButton2_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSplitButton3
            // 
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem});
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.Image = global::EWPEditor.Plugin.Properties.Resources.Webdev_help;
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.Name = "toolStripSplitButton3";
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 30);
            this.toolStripSplitButton3.Text = "帮助";
            
            // 
            // 手册ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "手册ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 28);
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "手册";
            this.手册ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(Help_Click);
            // 
            // 关于ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "关于ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 28);
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "关于";
            this.关于ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(关于ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // contextMenuStrip1
            // 
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.contextMenuStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.toolStripSeparator1,
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem,
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem});
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Name = "contextMenuStrip1";
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 178);
            this.contextMenuStrip1.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ContextMenuStrip1_VisibleChanged);
            // 
            // 打开ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "打开ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "打开";
            this.打开ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.打开ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // 编辑ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "编辑ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "编辑";
            this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.编辑ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // 导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "导入本地内容";
            this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // 收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "收藏选中内容";
            this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // toolStripSeparator1
            // 
            this.toolStripSeparator1.Name = "toolStripSeparator1";
            this.toolStripSeparator1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 6);
            // 
            // 插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "插入选中内容";
            this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // 删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 28);
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "删除选中内容";
            this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
            // 
            // imageList1
            // 
            this.imageList1.ColorDepth = System.Windows.Forms.ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
            this.imageList1.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
            this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            // 
            // 导出文档ToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.导出文档ToolStripMenuItem.Name = "导出文档ToolStripMenuItem";
            this.导出文档ToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(180, 22);
            this.导出文档ToolStripMenuItem.Text = "导出文档";
            // 
            // openFileDialog1
            // 
            this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "openFileDialog1";
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.AutoSize = true;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 93);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 409);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // listView1
            // 
            this.listView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this.columnHeader1});
            this.listView1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
            this.listView1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.listView1.GridLines = true;
            this.listView1.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
            this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
            this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
            this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.listView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
            this.listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
            this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 409);
            this.listView1.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            this.listView1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventHandler(this.listView1_DrawItem);
            this.listView1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.ListView1_DoubleClick);
            this.listView1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ListView1_MouseClick);
            this.listView1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_Resize);
            // 
            // columnHeader1
            // 
            this.columnHeader1.Text = "";
            this.columnHeader1.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            this.columnHeader1.Width = 210;
            // 
            // toolStripTextBox1
            // 
            this.toolStripTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.toolStripTextBox1.Name = "toolStripTextBox1";
            this.toolStripTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(206, 30);
            this.toolStripTextBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripTextBox1_Enter);
            this.toolStripTextBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripTextBox1_Leave);
            this.toolStripTextBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.ToolStripTextBox1_KeyUp);
            this.toolStripTextBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripTextBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // toolStripProgressBar1
            // 
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(34)))), ((int)(((byte)(195)))), ((int)(((byte)(230)))));
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Name = "toolStripProgressBar1";
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(206, 22);
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripProgressBar1_VisibleChanged);
            // 
            // toolStripLabel1
            // 
            this.toolStripLabel1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
            this.toolStripLabel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.toolStripLabel1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(34)))), ((int)(((byte)(195)))), ((int)(((byte)(230)))));
            this.toolStripLabel1.Name = "toolStripLabel1";
            this.toolStripLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 0);
            // 
            // toolStrip2
            // 
            this.toolStrip2.GripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
            this.toolStrip2.ImageScalingSize = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
            this.toolStrip2.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripTextBox1,
            this.toolStripProgressBar1,
            this.toolStripLabel1});
            this.toolStrip2.LayoutStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLayoutStyle.VerticalStackWithOverflow;
            this.toolStrip2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 33);
            this.toolStrip2.Name = "toolStrip2";
            this.toolStrip2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 60);
            this.toolStrip2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.toolStrip2.Text = "toolStrip2";
            // 
            // MainPane
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(10F, 23F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei", 10.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.Name = "MainPane";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 502);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainPane_Load);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.MainPane_Resize);
            this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.contextMenuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip2.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
    
        }
    
    
        #endregion
    
        private ToolStrip toolStrip1;
        private ToolStripButton toolStripButton1;
        private ToolStripButton toolStripButton2;
        private ToolStripButton toolStripButton4;
        private ToolStripSplitButton toolStripSplitButton3;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 手册ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 关于ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip1;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 打开ToolStripMenuItem;
        public ImageList imageList1;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 导出文档ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripButton toolStripButton8;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 编辑ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 导入本地内容ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 收藏选中内容ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator1;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 插入选中内容ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripMenuItem 删除选中内容ToolStripMenuItem;
        private ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator3;
        private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
        private ToolStripSeparator toolStripSeparator2;
        private ToolStripButton toolStripButton13;
        private Panel panel1;
        private ToolStripTextBox toolStripTextBox1;
        private ToolStripProgressBar toolStripProgressBar1;
        private ToolStripLabel toolStripLabel1;
        private ToolStrip toolStrip2;
        public DoubleBufferListView listView1;
        private ColumnHeader columnHeader1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer DownloadingProgerssTimer;
     }

     }
```

```
 When the display is set,      

         <pre><code>
```

`                   toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = files.Count;

```
                toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;
                toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;

                toolStripLabel1.Text =  "0%";
                toolStripLabel1.Visible = true;`
          </code></pre>
```

The effect will be as follows, the first item of listView1 will be displayed at the position of toolStripProgressBar1 and toolStripLabel1

[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to minimally reproduce your issue by copying your designer file and stubbing out the event handlers. If I disable the owner draw, things seem to work. Based on the information available in your post, this might point to an issue in your drawing code (which doesn't seem to be shown).

Showing the progress bar and label are going to cause the list view to move. It might be something as simple as refreshing the list view when that happens so that you're drawing into the new bounds with a current `Graphics` context.

[image: screenshot]

---

```
public MainPane()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listView1.OwnerDraw = false;

    toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = false;
    toolStripLabel1.Visible = false;
    listView1.BackColor = Color.Azure;
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem($"Hello {i + 1}");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
    listView1.Refresh();

    toolStripTextBox1.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = 
        toolStripLabel1.Visible = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 50; 
        toolStripLabel1.Text = "Visible";

        BeginInvoke(()=>    
        {
        toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, Eventually I found out that it was caused by other code that had ui threads blocking.

Comment: Thx for letting me know! I don't know whether isolating the designer in this manner aided you in reaching that conclusion, but if so please consider marking my answer as helpful.

Comment: ok,but Not yet, it shows"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded"